# How to implement JWT with springboot and mongodb as database without using password

Tags: jwt

I am currently working on jwt demo project using spring boot and mongo db as database. There's some inbuilt class like USERDetails which have method like accountNonExpired, get password and etc.. But I don't want to use this password thing. I just want to validate my username and login without password. But the USERDetails inbuilt showing error if I don't use password. How to implement the things without password.